# How to create JavaScript object with multiple names for the same element?

Tags: javascript, object

I want to create object that contains multiple column names. So my object that I have now has only one column name:

```
var columnStruct = {ColumnName:"LAST_NAME"}
```

So I'm wondering if I want more column names should I add them with comma after my existing LAST_NAME or there is some other way to do that? Also I want to compare my object later to records from the loop. That should look like this:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < columnNames.length; i++) {
      if(columnNames[i] == columnStruct.ColumnName){
           console.log('Same');
      }else{
           console.log('Not The Same');
      }
}
```

Comment: You can create an array of them and see if your value exists in the array.

Comment: @vlaz Can you provide any example how to check if element exist in array?

Comment: In newer browsers `["a", "b", "c"].includes("b")` will return `true`, or alternatively - applicable for anything greater than IE8: `["a", "b", "c"].indexOf("b") != -1`

Answer (score -1):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

With ES6 you can do this:

```
var inventory = [
        {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
        {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
        {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
    ];

function findCherries(fruit) { 
    return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

console.log(inventory.find(findCherries));
```

Or

```
[1, 2, 3].includes(2);     // true
[1, 2, 3].includes(4);     // false
[1, 2, 3].includes(3, 3);  // false
[1, 2, 3].includes(3, -1); // true
[1, 2, NaN].includes(NaN); // true


var ri_names = ["LAST_NAME", "SECOND_NAME", "FIRT_NAME", "AGE"];
ri.names.includes("LAST_NAMES");
```

Also you can do:

```
var ri_names = ["LAST_NAME", "SECOND_NAME", "FIRT_NAME", "AGE"];
var a = ri_names.indexOf("LAST_NAME");
console.log(a) // 0
```

This return the position, then if result is > -1 the word is in array.

There are two form that find results in array,

Answer (score -2):

```
//you can not add more than one object with the same name like below!
var abc={object1:'somsthing',object1:'something else'};
//As you can see this wolud be a total duplicate!
//instead,Arraylize the object elements like...
var columnStruct = ["ColumnName:LAST_NAME","And more..."];
for(var i in columnStruct){
    if(columnStruct.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        var column=columnStruct[i].split(':');//NOw u have both the column name and its result in an array

        //below check to see that it is the right column u are checking...
        if(column[0].match('/\bColumnName\b/','ig')){

            //now compare this with the result u wanted to see if its the same...
            if(column[1].match('whatever')){}//for a string value
            //or
            if(column[1]=='whatever'){

            }else{
                //do something
            }

        }

    }
}

//Hope it helps...
```